# Increase Memory Usage for Python process on Windows

Tags: windows, python-2.7, out-of-memory

I have a python script that loads mp3 music files into memory using NumPY, manipulates certain parts of each song, and renders the multiple music files into one single mp3 file. It can very RAM intensive depending on how many mp3 files the user specifies.

My problem is that the script throws "Memory Error" when I attempt to provide 8 or more mp3 songs (each around 5MB in size).

I am running:

- Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit with 64 GB of RAM and 4 core processors
- 32 bit version of Python

When I run Task Manager to view the python.exe process I notice that it crashes when it exceeds 1GB of RAM.

Is there a way I can increase the 1GB limit so that python.exe can use more RAM and not crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to increase memory usage for a process. The problem was with the python module I was using. After updating to a newer version of the module I was not limited to 1 GB of RAM.

Answer (score -1):

There's a work around.
See [Increasing the Amount of Memory Available to a 32-bit Windows Application](https://www.coveros.com/increasing-the-amount-of-memory-available-to-a-32-bit-windows-application/).

Using Visual Studio command prompt:

> editbin /LARGEADDRESSAWARE “C:pathtoexeexecutable.exe”